# Is it possible to use phpMyAdmin with XAMPP on a PHP version older than 7.2.5?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to work on a website that uses PHP 7.2.2 locally on my computer. I've downgraded to this version of PHP in XAMPP, but when I try to launch phpMyAdmin I get the message:

PHP 7.2.5+ is required.

Currently installed version is: 7.2.2

Is it possible to work around this? Or do I have to live without phpMyAdmin while working on this website?

Thanks

I tried downgrading to PHP 7.2.2 in XAMPP which was successful. I was hoping phpMyAdmin would work as normal but I got the message above.

Comment: The third number in the version is the patch level, it (generally) doesn't matter for the sake of compatibility because it only contains bug fixes. I.e., you can use the latest 7.2.* version (which is 7.2.34) and functionally, it will behave the same as 7.2.2. Likewise, you should be able to update the website to 7.2.34 without breaking anything.

Comment: As PHP 7.2 is EOL since years, you should update it as soon as possible. And yes, phpMyAdmin is a tool with a pretty long history - as it was released in 1998 for the first time, there are older versions of it supporting PHP 7.2.2 and older

Comment: If you really want to use the old PHP version, you'll probably have to downgrade phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the packaged kit of XAMPP which contains all the pieces together, you should find a XAMPP version that has the appropriate software you require rather than individually downgrading or upgrading components. There are likely to be compatibility problems aside from finding a corresponding phpMyAdmin version and using the packages version that contains all the tested and confirmed software versions that work together is going to be better.

Of course, I should warn you that it's a bad idea to run outdated software; in particular PHP 7.2 has been end of life since 2020 and I quite recommend migrating to a newer version.

The required PHP versions can generally be found as part of the download page https://web.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and in this case, the current version 5.2.1 says it works with PHP 7.2. I'm not sure why you are getting an error message about the patch version (using Semantic Versioning, PHP should not have broken anything between 7.2.0 and 7.2.5) — but since you're having that problem anyway, you might have to roll back to phpMyAdmin 4.9.11, which is also basically end of life at this point.

In short: don't do this, but if you really want to then I suggest downgrading your entire XAMPP stack at once, and if you don't want to do that then you should be able to just downgrade your phpMyAdmin to version 4.9.11.